# Early 2010s Steampunk series aired in Sy-fy channel about a girl fighting a cult

Tags: story-identification, tv

All I remember was that during the late 2000s or early 2010s, there were shorts aired between programs (like ads, kinda like how "*Over The Garden Wall*" was aired in CN Network), the shorts were about a girl trying to steal a book from some kind of cult or evil empire.

The girl looked like *Alice* from "*Resident Evil*", I remember that the show had a steampunk aesthetic and one of the villains looked like the wind-up assassin from the first "*Hellboy*" movie.

I don't remember if the shorts were the entire series or were mere ads for a full series.

Comment: Live action or animated?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Live Action

Comment: All the series ever broadcast on SyFy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Syfy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is most likely RIESE (2009 - 2010). It aired as web shorts and on SyFy and then, put-together, as a mini-series that ran 1.5 hrs. The lead looked as you describe and it had wasteland and steampunk elements.

[image]

From [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1542543/):

> Riese, a seemingly random wanderer, is being hunted by a terrifying religious cult, The Sect. Traveling from nation to nation for years, she is accompanied only by a wolf, Fenrir. Together they must evade the assassins sent by the Sect - who'll stop at nothing to complete the task they failed to achieve many years ago. Her past is shrouded in mystery, as even Riese can't recall the events of the tragic night when her entire family was slaughtered and she was forced to flee into the wilderness. On her journey, she'll piece together her past, and her destiny, in a conflict that will hold the fate of the world in the balance - and the once peaceful kingdom of Eleysia will be the battlefield.

Comment: Yup, this is it

Answer (score 6):

A steampunk-esque action girl dressed like Alice from *Resident Evil* (i.e. black leather corset look) makes me think of Rebecca Fogg in the series [*The Secret Adventures of Jules Verne*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178161/) (2000).  It did air on the Sci-Fi Channel, and it's possible they used short segments as filler.

[image: Rebecca Fogg secret agent action girl]

Rebecca Fogg is a British secret agent who has adventures with her cousin Phineas (who has an advanced hot air balloon lair) and the titular Jules Verne, who is constantly dreaming up new steam-futuristic devices.

I'm not sure which episode you would have seen parts of, but a clockwork villain and a book of secrets both fit with the themes of the series.

Note that the recurring villain Count Gregory is half mechanical

[image: Count Gregory]

and they come across other mechanical constructs like the mechanical gunslinger "Steely Joe."

[image: Steely Joe says "Draw!"]

Comment: Nope, this isn't it, what I'm looking for is from is from late 2000s/early 2010s, this already looks older and looks "lighter", the series I'm talking about had a grim dark scenario, and the girl looking like Alice, I meant the post-apocalyptic version of her rather than the secret agent look, so... the same thing you shared but with a cape/hoodie and changing the latex/thin black leather for a thicker one, brown or black I think

Comment: About the Count Gregor, I don't think the face of the villain I'm talking is ever shown, what you posted look indeed like the wind-up assassin from Hellboy, but without a mask, the one I'm talking had a full mask, a full steampunk mask just like the Hellboy dude. Also, there were no robots, it was more medieval steampunk rather than futuristic one